# Can we customize the modern Wiki pages styles and layout?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, modern-team-site

I have already gone through the following URLS.

[Apply Custom Styles to the New (Modern) SharePoint Pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/197571/apply-custom-styles-to-the-new-modern-sharepoint-pages)

[Customizing SharePoint Modern Pages](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208167/customizing-sharepoint-modern-pages)

But that doesn't help me because its about Site Pages.

My question is:

Can we customize the Modern Wiki Pages with our own styles in SharePoint Online?

If yes then can any one share the reference?

Answer (score 1):

What are you referring to the Modern Wiki Pages? Could you offer a screenshot about your Modern Wiki Pages?

Here is an article about Supported and unsupported customizations for "modern" pages for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-pages

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your Wiki Page a script editor webpart and insert new scripts to build your styles.
To do, go to page, editor, insert, webpart and find Content and finaly Script Editor, like the picture

[image]

Afther that, you can insert new scripts in webpart to build your styles.
hope this help

Comment: I have clearly mentioned I am using Modern Layout, Not classic layout.